# problema com conversão de código C

Tags: c

Gostaria de transformar isso em código C já fiz tudo só estou com o problema na parte "Se `MEDIA >=6` E `FALTAS <=10` Então" principalmente na parte de E não sei como vou separar a conta.

```
Programa CalculoMedia2 
Var 
N1, N2, MEDIA: Real 
FALTAS: Inteiro 
Início 
Leia N1 
Leia N2 
Leia Faltas 
MEDIA ← (N1+N2)/2 
Se MEDIA >=6 E FALTAS <=10 Então 
 Escreva “Aluno aprovado com média: ”, MEDIA 
 Senão 
 Escreva “Aluno reprovado com média: ”, MEDIA 
Fim Se 
Fim
```

Comment: Se usar && deve funcionar. if (MEDIA >= 6 && FALTAS <= 10) {...

Comment: parece me que falta um pouco trabalho de pesquisa...

Comment: Seria melhor alterar a forma da sua pergunta. Alguém que queria se referenciar no futuro não entenderá do que se trata. Você precisa formular uma pergunta bem definida.

Comment: Matheus, referente ao *rollback* do @CiganoMorrisonMendez: não podemos converter nossa pergunta em outra totalmente diferente. Uma vez explicado o problema e obtida *pelo menos uma resposta*, não devemos alterar a essência da pergunta pois isso invalida as respostas dadas. Devemos abrir uma nova pergunta e linkar para a original explicando a nova situação.

Comment: Ou, no caso, editar a pergunta e acrescentar mais conteúdo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes usar o `&&` para representar a expressão `E`, ficando:

`if (MEDIA >= 6 && FALTAS <= 10)`

Answer (score 2):

**Portugol**:

```
Se MEDIA >=6 E FALTAS <=10 Então 
    Escreva “Aluno aprovado com média: ”, MEDIA 
Senão 
    Escreva “Aluno reprovado com média: ”, MEDIA 
Fim Se
```

**C**:

```
/*Observação: utilizei o nome minúsculo para as variáveis *media* e *faltas* porque uma boa prática de programação é utilizar todas as letras maiúsculas apenas em constantes.*/
if (media >= 6 && faltas <= 10) {
    printf("Aluno aprovado com média: %f", media);
} else {
    printf("Aluno reprovado com média: %f", media);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para representar a expressão E (and) em C, existe o operador `&&`, dessa forma:

```
if (MEDIA >=6 && FALTAS <=10)
```

Já vou adiantando aqui, quando você precisar usar OU em C, existe o operador `||`, se a expressão fosse assim  "Se `MEDIA >=6` OU `FALTAS <=10` Então", então:

```
if (MEDIA >=6 || FALTAS <=10)
```

Answer (score 1):

Solucionei o problema convertendo o código para:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
int main ()
{
    float N1, N2, MEDIA;
    float FALTAS;
    printf ("Primeira nota: ");
    scanf ("%f", &N1);
    printf ("Segunda nota: ");
    scanf ("%f", &N2);
    printf ("numero de faltas: ");
    scanf ("%f", &FALTAS);
    MEDIA= (N1+N2)/2;
    if (MEDIA >=6 && FALTAS <=10)
    printf ("\nAluno aprovado com media: %f\n", MEDIA);
    else
    printf ("\nAluno reprovado com media: %f\n", MEDIA);
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Se você diz "preciso usar números reais nas notas e inteiros nas faltas" então troque "float FALTAS;" por "int FALTAS;" e "scanf ("%f", &FALTAS);" por "scanf ("%d", &FALTAS);".